# if a bounded sequence xn in [a,b] converges to x0 then x0 belongs to [a,b]

Tags: convergence-divergence

If a bounded sequence xn in [a,b] converges to x0 then prove that x0 belongs to [a,b]. I don't understand here how can x0 belong to [a,b], it may be slightly greater than b too. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A convergent sequence is surely bounded. Since $a\le x_n\le b$, permanence of sign tells you that
$$
a\le\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\le b
$$

If you want a detailed proof, assume by contradiction that $x_0<a$. Then there exists $N$ such that, for $n>N$,
$$
|x_n-x_0|<\frac{a-x_0}{2}
$$
which implies
$$
x_n<x_0+\frac{a-x_0}{2}=\frac{a+x_0}{2}<a
$$
Contradiction.

Similarly for proving that $x_0\le b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is convergent and thus bounded, so there exists $M$ and $g$ such that

$$
|a_{n}|<M\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=g.
$$

This holds because we can find $M$ such that $[a,b]\in[-M,M].$ Then

$$
|g|=|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|<\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}M=M
$$
So
$$
g\in[-M,M]\qquad\text{and}\qquad{a_{n}}\in[-M,M],
$$
as desired.

Comment: A convergent (hence bounded) sequence need not converge to either its least upper bound or its greatest lower bound.

Comment: @egreg Whoops, you are right! How about it now?